# Can one work on a legacy .NET framework codebase on a Mac?

Tags: .net, macos, ide, legacy

From what I understand and from what I have seen online, the .NET Framework (not .NET Core) is something that can only be worked on on a Windows machine. Something to do with DLLs, which I am not too familiar with.

I would really just love to be able to work on my company's codebase on my Mac when I work from home. I have a VM working, which is fine, but I just really want to see if there is some way I can get it running on MacOS. Visual Studio Mac has not been working for me, and neither has Jetbrains Rider. I heard of some way to do this in VS Code, but I think there's only a C# plugin, and we use VB .NET :/

Would greatly appreciate help or some insight!

Comment: I think using parallels for mac it is possible but it will emulate the Visual Studio on Mac. You will need to keep a Windows setup on your machine.

Comment: I already have that. I just want to work completely on Mac. I feel that there has to be some way!

Comment: there is no way to run on Mac. because .NET Framework only runs on WIndows exclusively. See my answer below.

Comment: Ok, understood. I would love to migrate it over to .NET Core. Any advice? I assume it is not just copying and pasting code into new files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, .NET Framework only runs on Windows, and there's no port of .NET Framework on Mac.

For cross platform (for Windows, Mac, some distro of Linux such as Ubuntu, Fedora, Centos, Alpine), just use .NET Core 2.1 or later.

For more information, visit the "what is .NET" official page: 
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet